# MinGW not recognised through path variable

Tags: c++, eclipse, compiler-construction, path, mingw

Eclipse CDT in Windows 7 is showing warnings like this:
Error launching external scanner info generator (g++ -E -P -v -dD C:/Users/User/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/specs.cpp)

So I already set the path environment variable to C:\MinGW\bin, but if i type gcc --version in cmd the command  is not recognised. However, if I change the directory to C:\MinGW\bin, it works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Path variable is picky about spacing too. If you have spaces between semicolon and other directory listings, the variable may break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can type "path" in the cmd window in order to see the path that's in effect (make sure you appended a value to the path variable and didn't replace it entirely, no spaces, etc.)

If opening a new cmd or reboot doesn't help, you can use [process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) with a filter of "process name is cmd.exe" to see where exactly cmd.exe looks for gcc and why it is failing.